# Unable to create a constant value. Only primitive types are allowed

Tags: linq, entity-framework

While trying to work with set of DB objects I get an error.

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    var allRates = context.CurrencyRate;
    var rates = new List<CurrencyRate>();
    //get rates for selected currency types
    foreach (var newRate in newCurrencyRateList)
    {
        rates.AddRange(allRates.Where(r => r.CurrencyTypeId == newRate.CurrencyId).OrderByDescending(r => r.CreatedDate).ToList().Take(4));
    }

    //Delete old rates
    var oldRates = allRates.Except(rates);
    if (oldRates != null && oldRates.Any())
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Entities() - data model.

I get an Error on

```
oldRates.Any()
```

How it can be fixed?

Comment: What happens if you do oldRates.Count() > 0 ?

Comment: Do rates have an id? Try `var oldRates = allRates.Where(r => !rates.Any(r2 => r2.Id == r.Id));`

Comment: What is the type of object `context.CurrencyRate`? (it actually looks like a type, so I'm confused...)

Comment: @FrancisP you asked right question. I should do context.CurrencyRate.ToList() and everything is Ok now. Thank you!

Edit. context.CurrencyRate was of type ObjectSet<CurrencyRate>

Comment: Figured it would be there...I was expecting a more relevant name such as `context.CurrentRateSet` or something! ;)

Comment: @Sanya530: This might not be exactly what you want. It might be small enough, but what you're doing by putting a `.ToList()` there is you're loading the entire set of `CurrencyRate`s into memory from the DB. That might be fine for CurrencyRates, which there probably aren't many of, but it could be a troublesome habit to get into.